# Floating Label White Background Missing on Custom Theme

Tags: react-native-paper

I am learning react native paper and when implemented with my custom theme, the floating label background goes missing.

Below is my code

```
import { MD3LightTheme as DefaultTheme,PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import  HomeScreen  from './screens/Home/index';
import RegisterScreen  from './screens/Register/index';



const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const theme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  // Specify custom property
  myOwnProperty: true,
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
  // Specify custom property in nested object
  colors: {
    primary: '#0a4b7c',
  },
};


export default function App() {
  return (
    <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" options={{headerShown:false}} component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    </PaperProvider>
  );
}
```

**Floating label with default theme**

[image]

**Floating label with custom theme**

[image]